# Check first word in textarea (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, textarea

Hello is it possible to check the input in a textarea with an php or javascript

```
echo '<textarea name="TA" cols="50" rows="10">';
echo '</textarea>';
```

I have to check if the first word is select / insert / update.

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you using jQuery, by any chance?

Comment: If you want to prevent SQL injection you should not only check the first word. Is this your intension?

Comment: Yes. But it sounds like you're allowing users to write SQL queries against your database in a textarea input. This is a terrible idea. If you're doing this ... umm ... you should probably stop.

Comment: yes its for an oci site only for me so don't worry :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP

```
$words = explode(' ', $_POST['TA']);
switch (strtoupper($words[0]))
{
    case 'SELECT':
        echo 'Select';
    break;

    case 'UPDATE':
        echo 'Update';
    break;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var first_word = $('textarea[name="TA"]').val().split(' ')[0];
alert(first_word);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the textarea content in jQuery with:

```
var text = $('#mytextarea').val();
```

The first word:

```
var firstword = text.split(/\b/)[0];
```